# How to find the different nodes in two similar graph

Tags: graph, diff

I have two graphs, the nodes in each graph have possibly same or different values. Most parts of the two graph are identical. Only a few nodes have been added, deleted, or modified. I want to know whether there is any algorithm to find those nodes. Or, at least, to find a set of nodes which includes these nodes.

Comment: [This](https://www.cs.cmu.edu/~jingx/docs/DBreport.pdf) might give you some pointers.

Answer (score 0):

If your graph class has a list of the nodes it contains, then this might work:

public bool FindGrNodes (GraphClassName gr2)
{
foreach (GrNodeClassName nd1 in nameoflist1)
foreach (GrNodeClassName nd2 in nameoflist2)
if (nd1.value==nd2.value)return true;

return false;
}

Big O'Notation is O (n^2)

Comment: Additionally, if you want a list of the similar nodes of these graphs, you should change the method type of list type (node). In the method create a new list, and replace "return true" to "listname.Add (nd1). After the loop, return the list